# Monotonically decreasing function for multiplication product?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, arithmetic, elementary-functions

I have a set of numbers $S = [100,999]$ for which I want the maximum product $p$ such that $p = a \times b$ for all $a,b \in S$ also fulfilling some condition $C$. I would like $p$ to be monotonically decreasing to prevent generating and sorting all products before testing them.

My first attempt was to choose $a,b$ seeing $a \times b$ as a triangle (products to the right of $a = b$ eliminated) and using a row scan instead of a column scan, $b \geq a$ for all $a$. Testing using $S = [1,9]$,  $6 \times 9 > 7 \times 7$.

My second attempt was to attempt to choose $a,b$ to maximize $h(a,b) = a + b$, but ran into problems with $S = [1,9]$ at $h(3,8) = 11$ and $h(5,5) = 10$ though $3 \times 8 < 5 \times 5$.

Is there a method of choosing $a,b$ from $S$ such that $p$ is always decreasing or equal? Or is there a proof that there is no such method (without first calculating all $p$)?

Comment: I don't really get the question- you want a function defined on $S\times S$ such that...? How do you define "decreasing" since you are working on a product space?

Comment: The product always decreasing - ie, $9 \times 9 = 81$, $9 \times 8 = 72$, $8 \times 8 = 64$, etc

Comment: The question is still ambiguous. You ask if "there is a way of multiplying $a$ and $b$"- what does that mean? The product is a function, there are no other way of doing the multiplication. What you are searching for is another function with desirable properties, one of them is that it has to be decreasing. What about the other properties?

Comment: Rewrote the question, hopefully to make it more clear